# Why are 2 network calls using the same search string required before the UICollectionView decides there is data that needs to be refreshed?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a strange problem in a UIViewController that the user uses to search for a GIF.

There are essentially 2 issues:

1. The user has to enter the same search term twice before the UICollectionView triggers the cellForRowAt data source method after a call is made to `reloadData()`.
2. After you enter the search term the first time, `heightChanged()` is called, but the `self.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height` comes back as 0 even though I've confirmed that data is being received back from the server.  The second time you enter the search term, the height is a non-zero value and the collection view shows the cells.

Here is an example of how I have to get the data to show up:

1. Launch app, go this UIViewController
2. Enter a search term (ie. "baseball")
3. Nothing shows up (even though `reloadData()` was called and new data is in the view model.)
4. Delete a character from the search term (ie. "basebal")
5. Type in the missing character (ie. "baseball")
6. The UICollectionView refreshes via a call to `reloadData()` and then calls `cellForRowAt:`.

Here is the entire View Controller:

```
import UIKit

protocol POGIFSelectViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func collectionViewHeightDidChange(_ height: CGFloat)
    func didSelectGIF(_ selectedGIFURL: POGIFURLs)
}

class POGIFSelectViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //MARK: - Constants
    private enum Constants {
        static let POGIFCollectionViewCellIdentifier: String = "POGIFCollectionViewCell"
        static let verticalPadding: CGFloat = 16
        static let searchBarHeight: CGFloat = 40
        static let searchLabelHeight: CGFloat = 24
        static let activityIndicatorTopSpacing: CGFloat = 10
        static let gifLoadDuration: Double = 0.2
        static let gifStandardFPS: Double = 1/30
        static let gifMaxDuration: Double = 5.0
    }
    
    //MARK: - Localized Strings
    let localizedSearchGIFs = PALocalizedStringFromTable("RECOGNITION_IMAGE_SELECTION_GIF_BODY_TITLE", table: "Recognition-Osiris", comment: "Search GIFs") as String
    
    //MARK: - Properties
    var viewModel: POGIFSearchViewModel?
    var activityIndicator = MDCActivityIndicator()
    var gifLayout = PAGiphyCellLayout()
    var selectedGIF: POGIFURLs?
    
    //MARK: - IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet weak var GIFCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchGIFLabel: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            self.searchGIFLabel.text = self.localizedSearchGIFs
        }
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchField: POSearchField! {
        didSet {
            self.searchField.delegate = self
        }
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicatorContainer: UIView!
    
    //MARK: - Delegate
    weak var delegate: POGIFSelectViewControllerDelegate?
    
    //MARK: - View Lifecycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.setupActivityIndicator(activityIndicator: self.activityIndicator, activityIndicatorContainer: self.activityIndicatorContainer)
        self.viewModel = POGIFSearchViewModel(data: PAData.sharedInstance())
        if let viewModel = self.viewModel {
            viewModel.viewDelegate = self
            viewModel.viewDidBeginLoading()
        }
        
        self.gifLayout.delegate = self
        self.gifLayout.isAXPGifLayout = true;
        self.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = self.gifLayout
        self.GIFCollectionView.backgroundColor = .orange
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // This Patch is to fix a bug where GIF contentSize was not calculated correctly on first load.
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)) {
            self.viewModel?.viewDidBeginLoading()
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.heightChanged()
    }
    
    //MARK: - Helper Methods
    func heightChanged() {
        guard let delegate = self.delegate else { return }
        
        let height = self.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height + Constants.verticalPadding * 3 + Constants.searchLabelHeight + Constants.searchBarHeight + activityIndicatorContainer.frame.size.height + Constants.activityIndicatorTopSpacing
        print("**** Items in Collection View -> self.viewModel?.gifModel.items.count: \(self.viewModel?.gifModel.items.count)")
        print("**** self.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height: \(self.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height); height: \(height)")
        delegate.collectionViewHeightDidChange(height)
    }
    
    func reloadCollectionView() {
        self.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        self.GIFCollectionView.reloadData()
        self.GIFCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.heightChanged()
    }
    
    func imageAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIImage? {
        guard let previewURL = self.viewModel?.gifModel.items[indexPath.row].previewGIFURL else { return nil }
        
        var loadedImage: UIImage? = nil
        let imageManager = SDWebImageManager.shared()
        imageManager.loadImage(with: previewURL, options: .lowPriority, progress: nil) { (image: UIImage?, data: Data?, error: Error?, cacheType: SDImageCacheType, finished: Bool, imageURL: URL?) in
            loadedImage = image
        }
        return loadedImage
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScrollToBottom() {
        guard let viewModel = self.viewModel else { return }
        
        if viewModel.viewDidSearchMoreGIFs() {
            self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        } else {
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}

extension POGIFSelectViewController: POSearchFieldDelegate {
    func searchFieldTextChanged(text: String?) {
        guard let viewModel = self.viewModel else { return }
        viewModel.viewDidSearchGIFs(withSearchTerm: text)
    }
}

extension POGIFSelectViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print("**** CELL FOR ROW AT -> self.viewModel?.gifModel.items.count: \(self.viewModel?.gifModel.items.count)")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Constants.POGIFCollectionViewCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! POGIFCollectionViewCell
        guard let previewURL = self.viewModel?.gifModel.items[indexPath.row].previewGIFURL else {
            return cell
        }
        
        var cellState: POGIFCollectionViewCell.CellState = .dimmedState
        if self.selectedGIF == nil {
            cellState = .defaultState
        } else if (self.selectedGIF?.previewGIFURL?.absoluteString == previewURL.absoluteString) {
            cellState = .selectedState
        }
        
        cell.setupUI(withState: cellState, URL: previewURL) { [weak self] () in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: Constants.gifLoadDuration) {
                guard let weakSelf = self else { return }
                weakSelf.GIFCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            }
        }
        
        if cell.GIFPreviewImageView.animationDuration > Constants.gifMaxDuration {
            cell.GIFPreviewImageView.animationDuration = Constants.gifMaxDuration
        }
        
        cell.backgroundColor = .green
        return cell
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let viewModel = self.viewModel else { return 0 }
        return viewModel.gifModel.items.count
    }
}

extension POGIFSelectViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let selectedGIF = self.viewModel?.gifModel.items[indexPath.row],
              let delegate = self.delegate else {
                  return
              }
        self.selectedGIF = selectedGIF
        delegate.didSelectGIF(selectedGIF)
        self.reloadCollectionView()
    }
}

extension POGIFSelectViewController: POGIFSearchViewModelToViewProtocol {
    func didFetchGIFsWithSuccess() {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        print("**** didFetchGIFsWithSuccess() -> about to reload collection view")
        self.reloadCollectionView()
    }
    
    func didFetchGIFsWithError(_ error: Error!, request: PARequest!) {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}

extension POGIFSelectViewController: PAGiphyLayoutCellDelegate {
    func heightForCell(givenWidth cellWidth: CGFloat, at indexPath: IndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
        guard let image = self.imageAtIndexPath(indexPath) else {
            return 0
        }
        if (image.size.height < 1 || image.size.width < 1 || self.activityIndicator.isAnimating) {
            return cellWidth
        }
        
        let scaleFactor = image.size.height / image.size.width
        let imageViewToHighlightedViewSpacing: CGFloat = 4  // this number comes from 2 * highlightedViewBorderWidth from POGIFCollectionViewCell
        return cellWidth * scaleFactor + imageViewToHighlightedViewSpacing
    }
    
    func heightForHeaderView() -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
}
```

You'll see that the `heightChanged()` method calls a delegate method.  That method is in another UIViewController:

```
    func collectionViewHeightDidChange(_ height: CGFloat) {
        self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = height
    }
```

So, I can't figure out why I need to either delete a character from the search term and re-add it in order for the data to refresh even though the very first call populated the view model with new data.

It's bizarre.  Please help.

Comment: First comment is that there is a *lot* going on in that code that makes it hard to determine where the problem lies.  Breaking some of it out might help.  Calling reloadData() doesn't mean that the data will load.  Although it's not obvious in the code I'd expect the data load to be asynchronous, and that's probably why it's not there the first time.  The data loading needs to be driven the completion handler on the network call, not by VC.

Comment: Thanks @flanker, that's what the delegate method didFetchGIFsWithSuccess() is doing.  It's being called within another object when the network request has successfully retrieved the gifs.  

So, that's already being done.

Comment: It's unclear: Where exactly is updated `viewModel` and when is called `reloadData()`. Are they really consecutive in the same thread? Since it's UI Related, `reloadData()` needs to be called in main thread, but updating the model needs too (processing the next model can be done in a background thread, but not setting it, as the UI Delegate methods will rely on it.